# rails - using :select(distinct) with :has_many :through association produces invalid SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

```
User
has_many :posts
has_many :post_tags, :through => :posts

PostTag
belong_to :post
belongs_to :tag
scope :distincttag, :select => ('distinct post_tags.tag_id')
```

with Rails 3.0.4, i get invalid SQL:
SELECT post_tags.*, distinct tag_id...

at least one other person experienced the same problem: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/484938

feature or a bug?

thanks

Comment: OK, never mind, it does work. In other words, creating a scope under PostTag does work.  What doesn't work, however, is just chaining up a ".select": someuser.post_tags.select('distinct tag_id') will result in the above error.  Shouldn't "select" override the select implicit in the join/association?

Comment: `@user.post_tags.uniq.pluck(:tag_id)` might get you what you want

Answer (score 3):

Does not look like the right thing to put on a scope.

Maybe you are trying to accomplish this:

```
class PostTag < ...
  belong_to :post
  belongs_to :tag
  def distincttag
    find(:all, :select => 'distinct tag_id')
  end
end
```

Edit: now that I know what you need:

```
User
has_many :posts
has_many :post_tags, :through => :posts, :select => 'distinct tags.*'
# or, if you are not worried about database overhead:
has_many :post_tags, :through => :posts, :uniq => true
```

Reference: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/5/6/through-gets-uniq

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was very clear. The goal is to get the list of distinct tags for a user. Adding a method to PostTag won't work once you chain it up to a user: someuser.post_tags.distincttag - will result in an error, because post_tags is an array

Comment: Fabio, thanks, but unfortunately that won't work.  Your first edited example is using ":select => 'distinct tags.*', but the "tags.*" table here is not even a part of the join.  The second example, using "uniq", won't work because you are using "uniq" on the entire "post_tags" record (post_id, tag_id), whereas I want unique "tags" (just tag_id), not unique "post_tags".