# How to add unique condition to an association model in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, unique

I have a simple relationship

`Questionnaire has_many Answers`

I have multiple questionnaires. I want to get the latest 5 answers across distinct questionnaires.

If I do:

`Answer.find(:all, :order => "id desc" , :limit => 5)`

I get the last 5 answers but most of the time all 5 answers belong to the same questionnaire. How can I query the latest answers from distinct questionnaires something like

`Answer.find(:all, :order => "id desc" , :limit => 5, :conditions => "DISTINCT questionnaire.id") ??`

(the idea is to show an activity feed to an administrator e.g. user A replied to answers in questionnaire X on 11-11-2012, user B replied to answers in questionnaire Y on 01-11-2012 etc.)

Comment: your line `Answer.find(:all, :order => "id desc" , :limit => 5, :conditions => "DISTINCT questionnaires.id") ` should work for this job (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229284/rails-using-selectdistinct-with-has-many-through-association-produces-inv). What DB system are you using? PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Are you really still using Rails 2?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  `.find(:all...` was deprecated some time ago.

Comment: Also you should use `answers.questionnaire_id` not `questionnaires.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Postgres I would do

```
Answer.find(:all,
  :order => "answers.attr1 asc, answers.attr2 asc, answers.attr3 asc, ..." , :limit => 5,
  :select => "DISTINCT ON (answers.questionnaire_id) answers.*")
```

Note you might have to list every column in your answer table except questionnaire_id in the order clause, so Postgres can know for sure what you want to select, otherwise it might be ambigious and you might get a SQL error.

And **for gods sake** upgrade to Rails 3!

Rails 3:

```
Answer.order("answers.attr1 asc, answers.attr2 asc, answers.attr3 asc, ...").
  limit(5).select("DISTINCT ON (answers.questionnaire_id) answers.*")
```

Comment: I just copied pasted the code from another question; I am on Rails 3. It seems a pretty ugly solution, is this because it's in Rails 2? :)

Comment: Yes and no. In Rails 3 it would look better, but it's the same concept, will update the answer.
Just play with the order clause, it might not be necessary or you might have to list all the columns in there.

Comment: And if you mean "ugly" because of a little heavier SQL usage, with AREL you can only do so much. At the end you will always have to use some SQL if you want an efficient application. Or you can trade speed for not using SQL and use Ruby code and multiple SQL queries, but that may be considerably slower. You have to make the choice yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY to get the latest answers for each questionare, and limit to latest 5:

```
latest_answer_ids = Answer.group(:questionnaire_id).
                           order('MAX(answers.id)').
                           limit(5).maximum(:id).values
latest_answers = Answer.where(:id => latest_answer_ids)
```

If you need to do this as one query, you can use Arel to build a subquery like this:

```
answers = Answer.arel_table
latest_answers = Answer.where(:id =>
           answers.
           group(:questionnaire_id).
           project('max(id)')
  ).order('id desc').limit(5)
```

The benefit here is that the subquery will work in any DBMS.

Comment: It's still 2 queries. And I don't see why you would use group over distinct here. You're not really trying to group anything, you just want rows with distinct questionnaire_id.

Comment: It's not 2 queries - it's 1 roundtrip to the database with 1 query containing a subquery.  I have verified this in output logs.  Not all DBMS support DISTINCT ON as you are using it; GROUP BY is a SQL standard way to accomplish this.

Comment: I wasn't aware arel was capable of generating subqueries like that. Thumb up for that. But I am wondering which one performs better, I'd think distinct would since it's a single query, but not sure.